# Javascript sleep until key is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I did some research and found busy wait solutions. I don't want the processor to execute a loop in the script until I get a keypress event through JQuery.

How can I pull of something like sleepUntilKeyPress(), which is a function like sleep() in C but instead of waiting some especific time it waits for a keypress?

Comment: Why do you want to sleep? Why not just wait for the keypress event to be activated then go from there?

Comment: @MikeC I don't want the processor to keep running until that key is pressed. I want it to sleep, or work on other jobs. In other words: sleep until key is pressed, then I'll go from there.

Comment: You're thinking backwards.  Rather than **not** executing until a key is pressed, **do** execute when a key is pressed.

Comment: So you want the processor to keep doing it's job then do something when a key is pressed? Cool, then just do `$(element).keypress(function(e) { doThingWithKey(e); })` and you're done.

Comment: @zero298, execute what exactly, if I want to wait?

Comment: @JudismarJunior Whatever you would have executed in your loop.

Comment: @MikeC I'm not sure if you got it. Maybe I didn't make myself clear. I just want the jaascript interpreter to sleep, wait, delay, until a key is pressed, any key. Like asking the user: "press any key to continue algorithm execution" (in this case, the pause is to illustrate the algorithm steps)

Comment: @JudismarJunior And you're thinking about it backwards. If you hit a point where it should "wait" then just don't allow the user to move forward. Don't run whatever function moves it forward. In Javascript, you have to think in terms of event handlers, not in IO pauses like you would with a standard console application. It might be better if you described your actual problem because Javascript doesn't have what you're asking for. Not without freezing up the browser.

Comment: @MikeC, this last comment is really helpful for me. I wonder what should I do. Should I answer my own question, or is it a irrelevant question? Or perhaps you answer it so I can close. I'm kinda new to event handlers, I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking backwards.  Your function shouldn't wait for a keypress to do something, the function should do something whenever a key is pressed.  Maintain your data state in a scope that your key callback can reach and update your state on keypress.

You're trying to say:

```
while(!keypress){
    dontDoSomething();
}
```

You should be doing something more like:

```
on(keypress, doSomething);
```

Consider this idea:

```
var counter, ispressed, el;

// Bad
counter = 0;
ispressed = false;
el = document.getElementById("element");

el.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
    ispressed = true;
});

el.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
    ispressed = false;
});

while (1) {
    if (ispressed) {
        counter += 1;
    }
}

// Better
el.addEventListener("click", function () {
    counter += 1;
});
```

Let's forget about the fact that that `while` will lock up the program, (I don't even think the event listeners will trigger and I'm pretty sure the DOM will lock up), you're asking your program to waste time constantly checking to see if you're pressed a button yet.  Rather than do that, let the browser check for you with the built in [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and do what you would normally do when you find out that the button has been pressed.

Comment: That answers my question. Thanks!

I guess I worked so hard on the javascript algorithms first and forgot about the asynchronous events. I'll just have to rewrite one algorithm.

Answer (score -2):

```
var interval = window.setInterval(function () {
    // hang around and do nothing
}, 1000);

document.onkeypress = function () {
    if (/* some specific character was pressed */) {
        window.clearInterval(interval);

        // do some other thing, other thing
    }
};
```

Comment: Mike C comment is more relevant !

Comment: `setInterval` doesn't prevent execution like `sleep`. It just waits for an interval of time to pass before running a set of code. Other code can run during this wait.